# How to include a tab character in a parameter of a Castle Windsor configuration file

Tags: xml, castle-windsor

I'm trying to include a tab character in my windsor.config component configuration

```
  <component id="config.DPDConnectorSettings"
           type="RGB.DPDConnector.Configuration.DPDConnectorSettings, RGB.DPDConnector"
           service="RGB.DPDConnector.Contracts.IDPDConnectorSettings, RGB.DPDConnector"
           lifestyle="singleton">
  <parameters>
    <StartAtRow>0</StartAtRow>
    <ParcelNumberColumn>0</ParcelNumberColumn>
    <StatusCodeColumn>1</StatusCodeColumn>
    <TimeStampColumn>2</TimeStampColumn>
    <TimeStampColumnFormat>yyyyMMddHHmmss</TimeStampColumnFormat>
    <GenerateTimeStamp>true</GenerateTimeStamp>
    <NumberOfWorkers>4</NumberOfWorkers>
    <Seperator>&#x9;</Seperator> <!-- &#x9; is a tab character-->
    <Type3ExportPath>files</Type3ExportPath>
    <Filter>.txt,.csv</Filter>
    <DirectoryToWatch>import</DirectoryToWatch>
    <IncludeSubDirectories>true</IncludeSubDirectories>
    <PollingtimeInMinutes>0,3</PollingtimeInMinutes>
    <MaxRetryCount>4</MaxRetryCount>
    <Host>***</Host>
    <Port>21</Port>
    <UserName>***</UserName>
    <Password>***</Password>
    <TransferMode>Passive</TransferMode>
  </parameters>
</component>
```

The parameter `<Seperator>&#x9;</Seperator>` gets converted into `null`

Does anyone know how to include a tab character in my windsor.config file?

---

edit: See my answer below. At the moment it is not possible.

Comment: IMHO this is a bug. XML config trims all parameters, but fluent config does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is impossible at the moment (using Castle Windsor 2.5.2)

I've reported the bug to the Castle Team. ( http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-290 )

Config values are read using the following method:

```
public static string GetConfigValue(string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : value.Trim();
}
```

As you can see, the value.Trim() causes all whitespace characters, including the TAB character to be stripped from the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that it's ignored completely. Try with `Separator` instead:

```
<Separator>&#x9;</Separator>
```

Comment: If I put some random text into the parameter, it is not ignored.

Comment: I was looking for something that acts as an _empty_ character. Thank you for your answer because it led me to the answer in my case ;-) For me it's: `&#x0;`